# Do I need to use multiple GoogleMyBusiness API keys?

Tags: laravel, google-maps, api-key, google-my-business-api

My team and I are currently in the process of creating a website listing a number of local businesses and as part of our service we are going to be administrating their GoogleMyBusiness. Basically each business will have a page on out website containing their informaiton, such as phone numbers, address and such - including reviews, opening hours and a Google Maps integration.

My question is; is it possible to use GMB APIs to integrate reviews, opening hours and Google Maps for each of our customers on the same website (on different pages) and would we need to request unique API keys for each customer?

Answer (score 0):

You only need one key. Make sure to restrict the key so you can have multiple instances of your Google Maps